# Is it possible to run multiple python scripts in one qsub script using Sun Grid Engine?

Tags: python, linux, server, cluster-computing

What I want is a qsub script that goes something like this...

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
conda activate environment

python script1.py
python script2.py
python script3.py
```

... where the 3 python scripts are run on different nodes (or slots) on an SGE cluster.

Then I can just run the script...

```
qsub qsub_script.sh
```

... and the 3 python jobs run concurrently in parallel.
Is it even possible?
Thanks